# Symlink to a custom-made cache in the node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm, caching, symlink, package-managers

I am writing my own package manager for NodeJS. Any installed packages are stored in a `node-cache` folder like this:

`node-cache/x@1.0.0` 
`node-cache/y@2.0.0`

It is important that packages are named `package@version` so that multiple versions can be stored inside the cache. When adding a package to a NodeJS project, the node modules folder will contain symlinks to the cache like so:

`/node_modules/x` -> `/node-cache/x@1.0.0` 
`/node_modules/y` -> `/node-cache/y@2.0.0`

I got my code to do this, and tested the following case:

```js
// project/index.js
require("x");
```

With the `/node-cache` and `project/node_modules` structured as the examples I showed above. I also made it so that `x@1.0.0` does a `require("y")`, to ensure packages can correctly resolve each other in the cache.

I also set the env variable `NODE_PATH` to the `/node-cache` path to ensure modules are resolved in the cache directory and not locally. When running `node index.js`, `x@1.0.0` loads pefectly fine and is resolved. However `y@2.0.0` is not resolved and I get this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'y'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\samal\AppData\Local\node-cache\x@1.1.1\index.js
- A:\Downloads\test\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\samal\AppData\Local\node-cache\x@1.1.1\index.js:1:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\samal\\AppData\\Local\\node-cache\\x@1.1.1\\index.js',
    'A:\\Downloads\\test\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

This happens because of the fact my cached files are named `package@version` instead of just `package`, which I need to cache multiple versions of the same package. Node is searching for `/node-cache/y` as `require()`'d by `x@1.0.0`, however there is only a `/node-cache/y@2.0.0`. Removing the `NODE_PATH` env variable produces the same error.

I was wondering, what is the best solution to this without forcing the user to do any extra unneccesary work to get the package manager working, while maintaining its fast speed, and using symlinks or anything that doesn't require file system copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually very simple. The solution is to use the [--preserve-symlinks](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--preserve-symlinks) flag. For example `node --preserve-symlinks index.js`.

This ensures that the symlinks are resolved locally rather than in the cache, which is how this is meant to work.